# How can I disable the next button in liquid jquery carousel?

Tags: jquery

Im using jQuery Liquid Carousel plugin and i dont know how to disable previous and next button .Can you please help me??

Answer (score 2):

In the file jquery.liquidcarousel.js make the following changes:

Add this code on line 110 right after `$('> .wrapper > ul', divobj).animate({'marginLeft': -(currentposition * totalwidth)}, options.duration);`:

```
if (currentposition+visiblelis >= totallis ) {
  $(this).addClass("disabled");
}
$('> .previous', divobj).removeClass('disabled');
```

And this code on line 117 right after `$('> .previous', divobj).click(function(){` :

```
$('> .next', divobj).removeClass('disabled');
if ((currentposition - visiblelis) <= 0) {
  $(this).addClass("disabled");
}
```

The code adds a `disabled` class to the next and previous buttons. Then you can style them as you want.

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](http://www.nikolakis.net/liquidcarousel/) just above download link:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#liquid').liquidcarousel({
        hidearrows: true    //hide arrows if all of the list items are visible
    });
});
```

Comment: but i want to disable the next button if last item displays

Comment: first, don't post twice the same thing and with bold! Respect those who try to help you. Second, provide a live demo of what you have, third let us know what you tried. Forth provide complete questions, you didn't mention this parameter in your original question.